# Add a Java file in a Jpanel of another file

Tags: java, swing, import, jframe, jpanel

I have **2** Java files, the first one is the **main java code** behind the program. And second is a **jfx.Webview**. I've been trying for forever to include the **jfx.Webview** in a **JPanel** that I have on the first Java file. I'm new to Java, and it's definitely not as easy as i thought. Please, if someone with a better understanding could explain to me the proper way to get this done, that would be of great help.

Here are the 2 Java files after some cleaning up:

```
public class Xzibit07 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    generateUI();
}

private static void generateUI(){

    XzibitUI program = new XzibitUI();
    program.setVisible(true);    
    program.setTitle("Xzibit");

    ImageIcon logoIcon = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Data/Images/Logo.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(program.logoLabel.getWidth(), program.logoLabel.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    program.logoLabel.setIcon(logoIcon);
    program.logoLabel.setBounds((program.logoPanel.getWidth()/2 - program.logoLabel.getWidth()/2), 0, 0, 0);

    ImageIcon settingsIcon = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("Data/Images/Settings.png").getImage().getScaledInstance((program.logoPanel.getHeight()/4), (program.logoPanel.getHeight()/4), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    program.settingsLabel.setIcon(settingsIcon);

    program.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    program.logoPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}
}
```

And the second:

```
public class XzibitWeb implements Runnable {

public String webPage = "http://www.example.com";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new XzibitWeb());

}

@Override
public void run() {

    JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();

    Platform.runLater(() -> {

        WebView view = new WebView();
        jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(view, 1024, 400));
        view.getEngine().load(webPage);
    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do this

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm

From your code i think you are not adding the jfxPanel to the frame.